Amazon Bedrock Knowledge Bases with Conversation history
I am planning to implement a chatbot using Amazon Knowledge base, but the documentation doesn't state its support for conversation history pretty well.
What I could find is that the session ID retrieved in the first interaction can be valid to up 24h, so if I keep sending the same sessionId, it will remember my conversation, but that doesn't solve my problem, which is giving the user the ability to talk with documents and retrieve the conversation to keep it at any moment, not only 24h.
Have you done this kind of chatbot using Amazon Bedrock Knowledge Bases? Also, how would you customize the prompt? It seems that if I want to use conversation history and custom prompts I need to attach my Knowledge base with Amazon Agents, if you what would be the benefit of using it instead of just creating a Langgraph using Knowledge base as retriever only?
